# compute the volume of $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 4;x^2+y^2+(z-2)^2\leq 4$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

compute the volume of $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 4;\,x^2+y^2+(z-2)^2\leq 4$
I noticed that the upper bound is $2+\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$  and the lower bound is $-\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$.
So the volume must be $\int_{-2}^{2} \int_{-2}^{2} \int _{-\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}^{2+\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}dx\,dy\,dz$
and then I stay with $\int_{-2}^{2} \int_{-2}^{2} 2+\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}dx\,dy\,dz$
which leads to
$8-\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2} R\sqrt{4-R^2}\,dR\,d\theta=8-2\pi\frac{8}{3}$.
which seems to be wrong.
A. where am I wrong?
b. does anyone have more effective way to solve it?

Comment: You want to compute the volume of the intersection?

Comment: yes that what I want.

Comment: For a start, your limits for $z$ are wrong. They should be $0$ and $2$. Also I don't think it's wise to integrate wrt $z$ then make your substitutions into polar form later. Do the substitutions first.

Comment: why z should begin with 0? this is a sphere, it should begin with -2? no?

Comment: I believe that z depends on x and y so actually it's true, the limits of x and y might be wrong though I fixed it.

Comment: The original two spheres have $-2 \le z \le 2$ and $0 \le z \le 4$. The intersection of these gives $0 \le z \le 2$.

Comment: so, why everyone claims that at the intersection z=1? @tomi

Comment: I can't insert an image in a comment so I will add an image to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The two inequalities describe two spheres with radius $2$. One has a centre at $(0,0,0)$ and the other has a centre at $(0,0,2)$.

The volume required is the intersection of the two spheres. By symmetry, we can treat this as the sum of two "caps". Find the volume of one of those and double it.

Because of the symmetry, I would find the volume of the cap as a volume of revolution.

[image]

Comment: I thought about it. do you undertand why my method failed?

Comment: I don't know. What are your $R$ and $\theta$ ? Did you try to change to cylindrical polar coords?

Comment: yep this should be a polar cylinder.

Comment: OK. I'll comment under your question rather than under my answer!

Comment: it's much clearer, can you explain me why everyone says that z=1? from my understanding, z *ranges* from 1 to 2

Comment: $z=1$ at the intersection of the two spheres! It is of course not equal to 1 in all the range of integration.

Answer (score 1):

Given 2 spheres intersects at $z=1$, which gives on $xy$ plane circle $x^2+y^2=3$. As is very good  suggested on other answer let's consider volume in intersection as double "cup":
$$\underset{x^2+y^2 \leqslant 3}{\iint}\int_{1}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}dxdydz$$

and now you can use polar coordinates.

Comment: are you sure that both intersect only on z=1? what about z=0.5?

Comment: ohh I see you claim that, the lower bound is 1.

Comment: Yes. From 2 "cups" I took upper.

Answer (score 1):

You can notice that the intersection of the two spheres yields $z=1$, this means that $\rho^2=x^2+y^2=3$. Therefore your desired volume should be given by:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}\int_{2-\sqrt{4-r^2}}^{\sqrt{4-r^2}}r\, dz dr d\theta$$

You can check [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705935/find-volume-between-two-spheres-using-cylindrical-spherical-coordinates) for further reference.

**Edit to complement the approach proposed by @Tomi:**

You can alternatively notice that this volume is just twice the volume of the upper "cap". The radius of the polar coordinates is $\sqrt3$ and $z$ ranges from 1 to $\sqrt{4-\rho^2}$. So you can compute the are as:

$$2\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}\int_{1}^{\sqrt{4-r^2}}r\, dz dr d\theta$$

Comment: sorry , I don't understand this, (0,0,0) is on both spheres, and obviosly z/=1

Comment: I thought you were using cylindrical coordinates! Could you elaborate more on the transformation that you are using?

Comment: now I'm really confuesed; you integrate first by z. switch to polar, and then says that z ranges from 1 to 2. right? what I don't get is why you just don't take the radius from 0 to 2. shouldn't it be determined by the algebric expression of z? the bounds on the first place? what does it mean if I take the bounds from 0 to 2?. also, why you take 2pi instead of theta from 0 to pi, and double it. it's the same number, but it has a different meaning and reaons.

Comment: Are you familiar with Cylindrical Coordinates? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system

Comment: after second thought, I don't understand why you use cylinder coordinates instead of polar ones. (after you integrate the inner one).

Comment: It's essentially the same, I added some further comments that you can use to complement the answer from @Tomi.  Moreover, your proposed solution does not work because you have the wrong integration limits.

Comment: shouldn't it be $\pi$ on the outer limit? as this only half revolution.

Comment: No. It is a full revolution in the plane $xy$.